# What's a Fail-safe Way to Update Python CSV

Tags: python, csv

This is my function to build a record of user's performed action in python csv. It will get the username from the global and perform increment given in the `amount` parameter to the specific location of the csv, matching the user's row and current date.

In brief, the function will read the csv in a list, and do any modification on the data before rewriting the whole list back into the csv file.

Every first item on rows is the username, and the header has the dates.

```
Accs\Dates,12/25/2016,12/26/2016,12/27/2016
user1,217,338,653
user2,261,0,34
user3,0,140,455
```

However, I'm not sure why sometimes, the header get's pushed down to the second row, and data gets wiped entirely when it crashes.

Also, I need to point out that there maybe multiple script running this function and writing on the same file, not sure if that causing the issue.

I'm thinking maybe I can write the stats separately and uniquely to each users and combine later, hence eliminating the possible clashing in writing. Although would be great if I could just improve from what I have here and read/write everything on a file.

Any fail-safe way to do what I'm trying to do here?

```
# Search current user in first rows and updating the count on the column (today's date)
# 'amount' will be added to the respective position
def dailyStats(self, amount, code = None):
    def initStats():
        # prepping table
        with open(self.stats, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row:
                    self.statsTable.append(row)
                    self.statsNames.append(row[0])

    def getIndex(list, match):
        # get the index of the matched date or user
        for i, j in enumerate(list):
            if j == match:
                return i

    self.statsTable = []
    self.statsNames = []
    self.statsDates = None

    initStats()
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    user_index = None
    today_index = None

    # append header if the csv is empty
    if len(self.statsTable) == 0:
        self.statsTable.append([r'Accs\Dates'])
        # rebuild updated table
        initStats()

    # add new user/date if not found in first row/column
    self.statsDates = self.statsTable[0]
    if getIndex(self.statsNames, self.username) is None:
        self.statsTable.append([self.username])
    if getIndex(self.statsDates, today) is None:
        self.statsDates.append(today)

    # rebuild statsNames after table appended
    self.statsNames = []
    for row in self.statsTable:
        self.statsNames.append(row[0])

    # getting the index of user (row) and date (column)
    user_index = getIndex(self.statsNames, self.username)
    today_index = getIndex(self.statsDates, today)

    # the row where user is matched, if there are previous dates than today which
    # has no data, append 0 (e.g. user1,0,0,0,) until the column where today's date is match
    if len(self.statsTable[user_index]) < today_index + 1:
        for i in range(0,today_index + 1 - len(self.statsTable[user_index])):
            self.statsTable[user_index].append(0)

    # insert pv or tb code if found
    if code is None:
        self.statsTable[user_index][today_index] = amount + int(re.match(r'\b\d+?\b', str(self.statsTable[user_index][today_index])).group(0))
    else:
        self.statsTable[user_index][today_index] = str(re.match(r'\b\d+?\b', str(self.statsTable[user_index][today_index])).group(0)) + ' - ' + code

    # Writing final table
    with open(self.stats, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(self.statsTable)

    # return the summation of the user's total count
    total_follow = 0
    for i in range(1, len(self.statsTable[user_index])):
        total_follow += int(re.match(r'\b\d+?\b', str(self.statsTable[user_index][i])).group(0))

    return total_follow
```

Comment: Could explain in detail your problem and what output are you expecting. It is impossible to help with few informations. Also, try to reproduce your problem in a MWE.

Comment: Hi @jlandercy I'd love to give more info but there was no error. When I check the csv, 2 things might happen, either the 1st row is pushed down, creating a new header or data is completely wiped (this one is rare but has had happened a few times). Also, I do need to point out that there might be multiple scripts running and writing on the same file. I'm self-taught, so my vocabulary is limited to some degree, what's a MWE?

Comment: We do not know what you aim to do, you just send a code and a file structure but no description of what the code should do.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Z says, concurrency is more likely the cause of your problem.
I will add that CSV format is not suitable for Database storing, indexing, sorting, because it is plain/text and sequential.

You could handle it using a RDBMS for storing and updating your data and periodically processing your stats. Then your CSV format is just an import/export format.

[Python offers a SQLite binding](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html) in its Standard Library, if you build a connector that import/update CSV content in a SQLite schema and then dump results as CSV you will be able to handle concurency and keep your native format without worring about installing a database server and installing new packages in Python.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about the same issue here pertaining the database storing. Thanks for your input, will look more into this.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I need to point out that there maybe multiple script running this function and writing on the same file, not sure if that causing the issue.

More likely than not that is exactly your issue. When two things are trying to write to the same file at the same time, the outputs from the two sources can *easily* get mixed up together, resulting in a file full of gibberish.

An easy way to fix this is just what you mentioned in the question, have each different process (or thread) write to its own file and then have separate code to combine all those files in the end. That's what I would probably do.

If you don't want to do that, what you can do is have different processes/threads send their information to an "aggregator process", which puts everything together and writes it to the file - the key is that *only* the aggregator ever writes to the file. Of course, doing that requires you to build in some method of interprocess communication (IPC), and that in turn can be tricky, depending on how you do it. Actually, one of the best ways to implement IPC for simple programs is by using temporary files, which is just the same thing as in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thanks your input, would have never known there's such a thing as aggregator without you.